# Is there a way to Replace(*) in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

So simply I'm doing something similar to:

```
select 
    [BadData], [WorseDate], [IQuitData]
into 
    #BadDataTempTable
from 
    SomeoneElsesMess
```

what I want to do now is something similar to:

```
Select 
    Replace(#BadDataTempTable.*, ',', ' ')
from 
    #BadDataTempTable -- Replace all commas in every column `with a space--`
```

Is this possible? If so please show me the easiest (non-function) way to do so.

Thanks. SQL Server 2012 I think. I'm using SSMS 17

Comment: No, it's not possible. You have to do the `REPLACE` for each column.

Comment: The ways you could do it are manually (write out all the column names with a replace) or dynamically (if there's too many columns, you'd use this and retrieve the column names from, say, information_schema.columns). That said, if the data is that bad, I'm not sure what a replace like that is going to do...

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean by dynamically. Can you show me?

Answer (score 1):

No, the columns have to be specified. You could use dynamic SQL to build your update / query. Then just copy the command you want from the results.

Maybe this will help get you started:

```
BEGIN
    -- Set the replace value
    DECLARE @ls_replaceValue NVARCHAR(MAX) = ',';
    -- Set the with value
    DECLARE @ls_withValue NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' ';
    -- Set the table name we want to query 
    DECLARE @ls_table NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'some_table';

    -- Get all of the columns and provide the replace parameters
    DECLARE @ls_columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    SELECT  @ls_columns = @ls_columns + ', ' + name + ' = REPLACE(' + name + ', ' + '' + '''' + REPLACE(@ls_replaceValue, '''', '''''''') + '''' + ', ' + '''' + REPLACE(@ls_withValue, '''', '''''''') + '''' + ')'
    FROM    sys.all_columns
    WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(@ls_table)
        AND collation_name IS NOT NULL; -- Skip columns that aren't character based

    -- Remove the first ', ' from the column list
    SET @ls_columns = SUBSTRING(@ls_columns, 3, LEN(@ls_columns));
    IF @ls_columns = ''
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Table not found'
        RETURN
    END

    -- Build a query
    DECLARE @ls_query_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    SET @ls_query_sql = 'SELECT ' + @ls_columns + ' FROM ' + @ls_table;

    -- Show the results
    SELECT @ls_query_sql AS querySQL;
END
```

Comment: This is a little too advanced for me, Is there any doc's i can read about this? also im not trying to update the tables. Only the output needs to replace the ,'s. For bettter context we are taking the data from sql and "exporting" to .csv then importing that .csv into SalesForce.

Comment: You will need to adjust the 7th line (change "some_table" to your table name). This SQL block will get all the columns for a given table and output a query that you can execute.

Answer (score 0):

Just since the OP asked about how you might do this in dynamic SQL, here's how I'd approach it. Basically get the table schema information and concatenate all the columns, plus the `REPLACE` logic you want using `FOR XML`. This basically constructs the statement Rigerta posted, but does it dynamically.

```
use tempdb
go

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#SomeoneElsesBadData') is not null drop table #SomeoneElsesBadData
create table #SomeoneElsesBadData
(
    BadData varchar(250),
    WorseData varchar(250),
    IQuitData varchar(250)
)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = 'select ' 
    + stuff((select ', ' 
                 + name 
                 + ' = replace(' + name + ''','', '''')'
             from tempdb.sys.columns
             where object_id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#SomeoneElsesBadData')
             for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
    + ' into #BadDataTempTable
        from #SomeoneElsesBadData'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

All things being equal, the data should probably be cleaned before it gets into SQL, but reality is rarely fair.